# Finding the limit of a complicated expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I've never used *Mathematica* before, so I'm really struggling to use it right now. I have a complicated function

$\qquad \chi_{N}=\frac{[(2\cosh(J))^{N+1}(\lambda_{0}+\lambda_{1})^{N}((\mu_{0}+\mu_{1})b+2a\sinh(J))+(2\sinh(J))^{N+1}(\lambda_{0}-\lambda_{1})^{N})((\mu_{0}-\mu_{1})b+2a\sinh(J))]}{Z_{N}b}$

where

$\qquad Z_{N}=[(2\cosh(J))(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{0})]^{N}+[(2\sinh(J))(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{0})]^{N}$

and $\mu_{0},\mu_{1},\lambda_{0},\lambda_{1},J,a,b$ are all constants.

Anyways, I'm trying to compute $\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{\chi_{N+1}}{\chi_{N}}$
but I'm really struggling to get all the syntax right, and I've been plagued with errors. Does anyone have any suggestions for a newbie on how to do this? I imagine it's really simple for seasoned users but I'm at a loss.

This is what I tried inputting, just to get a feel for what I'm supposed to do, even though it's not the full expression.

```
Limit[
  (2Cosh[J]^(N + 1)(Subscript[λ, 0] + Subscript[λ, 1]))^(N)
    ((Subscript[μ, 0] + Subscript[μ, 1])
        (Subscript[λ, 1]e^(J) + Subscript[λ, 0]e^(-J)) +
      2 Sinh[J](Subscript[ν, 0] - Subscript[ν, 1])) +
    (2 Sinh[J]^(N + 1)(Subscript[λ, 0] - Subscript[λ, 1])^(N)
      ((Subscript[μ, 0] - Subscript[μ, 1])
         (Subscript[λ, 1]e^(J) + Subscript[λ, 0]e^(-J)) + 
      2 Cosh[J](Subscript[ν, 0] - Subscript[ν, 1]))), 
  N -> ∞]
```

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: You should show you own efforts first. Learn as much as you can from the [documentation](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/), try some code (you will need the function [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html), and then [edit] your question to include a minimum working example of what you have and an explanation of what your problem is.

Comment: First of all remove all `Subscript` in variable names, the explanation why will come later when you are more familiar with Mma but as a rule, of bring all sort of problems. 

Second, Mma is case sensitive and `Infinity` its not the same as `infinity, correct that.

Comment: Third `N` is the name of a function, don't use uppercase names for variables as they will collide with the ones defined by Mma.

Comment: @rhermans Thanks. I actually didn't input the     Subscript prefix, I guess that was added automatically. Thank you again.

Comment: After all the necessary changes your expression looks like this, please check,  `Limit[2*(λ0 - λ1)^n*((λ0/e^j + e^j*λ1)*(μ0 - μ1) + 
     2*(ν0 - ν1)*Cosh[j])*Sinh[j]^(1 + n) + 2^n*((λ0 + λ1)*Cosh[j]^(1 + n))^n*
    ((λ0/e^j + e^j*λ1)*(μ0 + μ1) + 2*(ν0 - ν1)*Sinh[j]), n -> Infinity]`. To that Mma will not find a limit as it looks like it doesn't exist.

Comment: @rhermans Wow thank you. I've been struggling to come to grips with the syntax and a worked example helps tremendously. If you posted that as an answer I would vote it to be the best one.

Comment: Also, be warned that Euler's number e is written as E in Mathematica (or you could use the functional form `Exp` if you're looking for powers of E).

Comment: @TeeJay rhermans meant to say: Don't use subscripted variables. You probably entered those using the keyboard shortcut for subscripts, but internally they are translated into Subscript[] constructions. The problem with these is that they are not actual symbols, though they may look and act like symbols in certain conditions (but this will bite you in other conditions). Use subscripts only for displaying equations, not for working with them. It will save you lots of trouble. If you have a dire need for them, you may resort to the Notation package.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  as its a consequence of a simple mistake that could be found in the documentation. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write your expression like this

```
2*(λ0 - λ1)^n*((λ0/E^j + E^j*λ1)*(μ0 - μ1) + 2*(ν0 - ν1)*Cosh[j])*
  Sinh[j]^(1 + n) + 2^n*((λ0 + λ1)*Cosh[j]^(1 + n))^n*
  ((λ0/E^j + E^j*λ1)*(μ0 + μ1) + 2*(ν0 - ν1)*Sinh[j])
```

Using `Collect[%, j]` you can separate it on terms and it becomes more clear that in general the limit doesn't exist.

```
2^n E^-j λ0 μ0 ((λ0 + λ1) Cosh[j]^(1 + n))^n + 
 2^n E^j λ1 μ0 ((λ0 + λ1) Cosh[j]^(1 + n))^n + 
 2^n E^-j λ0 μ1 ((λ0 + λ1) Cosh[j]^(1 + n))^n + 
 2^n E^j λ1 μ1 ((λ0 + λ1) Cosh[j]^(1 + n))^n + 
 2^(1 + n) ν0 ((λ0 + λ1) Cosh[j]^(1 + n))^n Sinh[j] - 
 2^(1 + n) ν1 ((λ0 + λ1) Cosh[j]^(1 + n))^n Sinh[j] + 
 2 E^-j λ0 (λ0 - λ1)^n μ0 Sinh[j]^(1 + n) +
 2 E^j (λ0 - λ1)^n λ1 μ0 Sinh[j]^(1 + n) - 
 2 E^-j λ0 (λ0 - λ1)^n μ1 Sinh[j]^(1 + n) -
 2 E^j (λ0 - λ1)^n λ1 μ1 Sinh[j]^(1 + n) + 
 4 (λ0 - λ1)^n ν0 Cosh[j] Sinh[j]^(1 + n) - 
 4 (λ0 - λ1)^n ν1 Cosh[j] Sinh[j]^(1 + n)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm getting the hang of a lot of this now. I knew the limit wouldn't exist, but I just wanted to familiarize myself with the procedure before inputting the full expression.